# Javascript Methodname is replaced with !==

Tags: javascript, html

On the server lies a html file with javascript code included.
This javascript code includes a method called something like "CheckObject".

This file works for all users, except one specific (but important).
He gets a javascript error and in his browser sourcode appears something unbelievable:
The methodname "CheckObject" is replaced with "Check!==ect", means the "Obj" of the method name is replaced with !==.

Why could that be?

Hope anybody can help me!
Best regards

Comment: I wonder if this should be on http://superuser.com instead of here. It's more related to the browser going haywire than to programming.

Answer (score 0):

If he's using a browser that supports extensions (like Firefox, Chrome, and some others), it's probably worth disabling all of the extensions and seeing if the problem goes away.

If you haven't already, I'd completely clear his cache in case there was a bad page transfer once and the browser is reusing it.

I can't imagine how it would be happening reliably otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. He tried already Firefox and Internet Explorer. The same problem anyway.
This problem occurs also at all computers in his local network..